# Почему неверный результат при удаление значений из списка во время его обхода

Tags: python, list, список

Есть кусок кода:

```
def remitem(mylist):
        mylist2=mylist
        for item in mylist:
            if (mylist.count(item)==1):
                mylist2.remove(item)
        return mylist2
    print remitem([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему он возвращает [6,8] , цикл то идет по одному списку, а удаляет из другого - по логике он же должен возвращать []?

Comment: Так проще:

    result = filter(lambda x: mylist.count(x) > 1, mylist)

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov да. Для небольших списков. Иначе -- вспомогательный словарь.

      d = {}
      for item in mylist:
        if item in d: d[item] = False
        else: d[item] = True
      result = filter (lambda x: d[x], mylist)

Comment: связанный вопрос: [В чем разница между двумя циклами for: при удалении элементов во время обхода списка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/596463/23044)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

потому что это один и тот же список, т.к. это mutable (можешь почитать подробнее, поискав в интернете по этому слову)

если тебе нужна копия этого списка -- воспользуйся командой copy или mylist2=mylist[:]

Comment: т.е. это mylist2=mylist - просто создание ссылки на одну и ту же область памяти?

Comment: да, это так