# Удалить уникальные значения из list

Tags: python, list, count

Подобная [тема была](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/248659/178576), но ответ мне не ясен. Почему удаляет из списка не все значения?

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for i in data:
     if data.count(i) == 1:
           data.remove(i)
print data
```

Печатает `[2,4,6]`

Comment: связанные вопросы: [В чем разница между двумя циклами for: при удалении элементов во время обхода списка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/596463/23044) и [Как найти все дублирующиеся элементы в списке и количество их повторов?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533108/23044)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Самое главное, что Вы должны запонить - **никогда** не изменяйте размер массива во время прохождения по нему.

Давайте посмотрим, как изменение размера массива влияет на логику цикла:

```
In [3]: l = list(range(6))

In [4]: for x in l:
   ...:     print(x)
   ...:     l.remove(x)
   ...:     
0
2
4
```

Взглянем на это через призму замечательных ASCII рисунков:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |  <- l
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  ^
  x
```

Выведем на печать `x` и удалим его из списка:

```
# print(0)

+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |  <- l
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  ^
  x
```

Переместимся на следующий элемент, как завещал нам великий Guido van Rossum:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |  <- l
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
      ^
      x
```

Для закрепления, повторим действия: напечатаетаем, удалим и перейдем на следующую итерацию цикла:

```
# print(2)

+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |  <- l
+---+---+---+---+---+
      ^
      x (до перехода)


+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |  <- l
+---+---+---+---+---+
          ^
          x (после перехода)
```

Очевидно, что изменяя размер массива во время итерирования по нему, на свет рождается еще одно маленькое зло, которое может привести (и приводит) к ошибкам.

Самый короткий рабочий эквивалент данного цикла представил @andreymal:

```
data = [x for x in data if data.count(x) > 1]
```

Но у представленных решений есть один общий недостаток - они имеют квадратичную сложность.

```
In [9]: data = list(range(10000))

In [10]: %timeit [x for x in data if data.count(x) > 1]
1 loops, best of 3: 1.66 s per loop
```

Стандартная библиотека Python предоставляет класс `Counter`, который подсчитает количество вхождений каждого элемента. Таким образом, скорость получится линейной (строго говоря, амортизированно линейной):

```
In [11]: from collections import Counter

In [12]: def f(xs):
   ....:     counter = Counter(xs)
   ....:     return [x for x in xs if counter[x] > 1]
   ....: 

In [13]: %timeit f(range(10000))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.33 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Как писали в предыдущем ответе, массив меняется, а индекс не меняется, по сути получается лишнее смещение на следующий элемент при удалении другого элемента.

Когда мне лень мудрить, а список чистить надо, я создаю копию массива:

```
for i in tuple(data):
    if data.count(i) == 1:
        data.remove(i)
```

(tuple вместо list, потому что он, говорят, производительнее)

Когда мне мудрить не лень, я могу завести отдельный список под удаляемые элементы:

```
rm = []
for i in data:
    if data.count(i) == 1:
        rm.append(i)
for x in rm:
    data.remove(i)
```

Когда я вспоминаю про существование генераторных выражений, я пишу вариант-однострочник:

```
data = [x for x in data if data.count(x) > 1]
```

Четвёртый известный мне вариант приведён в другом ответе.

Comment: последнее красиво. надо почитать про питон

Comment: @splash58: код в ответе квадратичный. Если заранее неизвестно, что `data` маленький, то лучше: `non_uniq = [item for item, count in Counter(data).items() if count > 1]` (линейный алгоритм)

Answer (score 0):

если добавить печать

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for i in data:
     print i
     if data.count(i) == 1:
           data.remove(i)
print data
```

получим

```
1
3
5
```

видимо в питоне, когда вы удаляете элемент, индекс остается, и вы шагаете через один. т.е. после удаления надо опять с тем же индексом проверять элемент. Проще всего запусть цикл по убыванию индекса

вот так удалим всё (мой первый код на питоне :), наверняка можно красивее)

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
i = len(data)-1
while i>=0  :
     if data.count(data[i]) == 1:
           data.remove(data[i])
     i = i-1
print data
```

Comment: Попробуйте изменить (дополнить?) ответ, исходя из предположения, что менять размер массива во время прохождения по нему - зло.

Comment: если б я что-нить про этот язык еще понимал :)

Comment: В таком случае могу порекомендовать книгу [Dive into Python](http://www.diveintopython3.net/) и [PyCharm educational edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm-educational/)

Comment: Спасибо! обязательно почитаю. я несколько раз видел код на нем, мне понравилось