# Как найти все повторяющиеся элементы в списке и количество повторов?

Tags: python, массивы, алгоритм, list, повторы

Нужна функция, которая, например, для списка:

```
[10, 10, 23, 10, 123, 66, 78, 123]
```

вернёт:

```
{10: 3, 123: 2}
```

Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### Реализация

#### Первый способ:

```
A = [10, 10, 23, 10, 123, 66, 78, 123]
counter = {}

for elem in A:
    counter[elem] = counter.get(elem, 0) + 1

doubles = {element: count for element, count in counter.items() if count > 1}

print(doubles)
```

#### Второй способ:

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter(A)
```

#### Третий способ:

```
from collections import defaultdict
counter = defaultdict(int)
for elem in A:
    counter[elem] += 1
```

### Оценка сложности алгоритмов

Стоимость составления списка-счетчика: нужно n раз вставить в словарь значения. Вставка состоит из двух операций: сначала проверка, есть ли такой номер в словаре и, собственно, вставка - все вместе O(1) среднем или O(n) в худшем для редких случаев, когда у всех элементов одинаковый хеш. То есть стоимость составления счетчика - O(n) в среднем, O(n^2) в худшем.

Следущий шаг - отфильтровать только нужное. В худшем случае нужно пройти по всему счетчику - снова n операций по O(1) или в худшем O(n) - взять из словаря, сравнить с единицей, записать в новый словарь. В среднем O(n).

Итого O(n) в среднем или для специально подготовленных данных O(n^2) в худшем.

### Результаты бенчмарков

Обновление с большим массивом:
Минутка замеров:

```
import timeit

non_Counter = \
"""counter = {}
for elem in A:
    counter[elem] = counter.get(elem, 0) + 1"""

setup = "import random\n" \
        "A = [random.randint(0, 100) for r in range(10**6)]"

print(timeit.repeat(non_Counter, setup=setup, number=10))

non_Counter = """Counter(A)"""

setup = "import random\n" \
        "from collections import Counter\n"\
        "A = [random.randint(0, 100) for r in range(10**6)]\n"

print(timeit.repeat(non_Counter, setup=setup, number=10))

non_Counter = \
"""counter = defaultdict(int)
for elem in A:
    counter[elem] += 1"""

setup = "import random\n" \
        "from collections import defaultdict\n" \
        "A = [random.randint(0, 100) for r in range(10**6)]"

print(timeit.repeat(non_Counter, setup=setup, number=10))
```

Результат:

```
[2.461800295429222, 2.456825704148736, 2.50377292183442]
[0.7278253601108151, 0.7268121314832463, 0.7283143209274385]
[1.3038446032438102, 1.3117127258723897, 1.3013156371393428]
```

Как видно из результатов, быстрее всех решение с Counter.

### Почему такие результаты

Объяснение проигрыша наивного решения со словарем:

Для того, чтобы получить значение из словаря, необходим хеш переменной `elem`. Значение хеша необходимо дважды: для того, чтобы получить предыдущее значение и для того, чтобы установить новое. Очевидно, вычислять два хеша - производить двойную работу. Замеры:

```
non_Counter = \
"""
args = [None, None]
for elem in A:
    hash(elem)
    hash(elem)"""

setup = "import random\n" \
        "A = [random.randint(0, 100) for r in range(10**6)]\n" \
        "counter = {}"

print(timeit.repeat(non_Counter, setup=setup, number=10))
[1.4283945417028974, 1.433934455438878, 1.4188164931286842]
```

Как видно, лишнее вычисление съедает 0.7 секунд или 30% от общего времени. К сожалению, нет стандартной возможности получить значение из словаря по значению хеша. В классе Counter функция подсчета написана на более низком уровне (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#L2284) и вызывает функции _PyDict_GetItem_KnownHash, _PyDict_SetItem_KnownHash, что значительно экономит время.

Также каждый раз при вызове метода `get(elem, 0)` вызывается инструкция LOAD_ATTR, которая должна найти нужный метод по имени. Так как метод не изменится, можно вынести его поиск за цикл. Трюк старый, надо с ним быть внимательнее в новых версиях интерпретатора, может это более не работает:

```
getter = counter.get
for elem in A:
    counter[elem] = getter(elem, 0) + 1

[1.917134484341348, 1.9207427770511107, 1.9153613342431033]
```

Удалось сэкономить еще 0.6 секунд.

Comment: Использование `.get()`, `filter(lambda)` некрасиво выглядит. Если вам profiler говорит, что подсчёт элементов является узким местом и `Counter()`  не достаточно быст для ваших целей, то в этом случае можно попробовать `collections.defaultdict`, тогда код выглядит как: `for elem in A: counter[elem] += 1` и `dups = {e: count for e, count in counter.items() if count > 1}` чтобы дубликаты найти. Если производительность подсчёта элементов с помощью словаря интересует, то посмотрите [Python - Is a dictionary slow to find frequency of each character?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2522152/4279)

Comment: @jfs, я когда писал ответ даже не задумывался, что можно пробовать оптимизировать такие простые вещи. А оказалось, что по оптимизации строки `counter[elem] = counter.get(elem, 0) + 1` можно целую статью написать с объяснениями, экспериментами и выкладками `dis`. Даже если перед циклом написать `getter = counter.get`, то производительность возрастает на 20%. Ну как так-то?

Comment: Меня смущает тот факт, что используется неидиоматичный код, без хорошей на то причины. И мне хорошо известно, что много вариантов по микрооптимизации можно придумать (нажмите на ссылку из моего предыдущего комментария)—я не понимаю к чему тут оптимизировать, но если вас это интересует, то я вижу в ответе пример кода (`filter(lambda)`), который одновременно некрасивый и медленный (я привёл пример, как более идиоматично и эффективно данную задачу решить в прошлом комментарии).

Comment: @jfs, согласен, `if count > 1` выглядит лучше - изменил.

Comment: Хорошо, что `filter(lambda)` убрали. Что мешает `.items()` вызывать, чтобы избежать `counter[elem]` как показано в моём первом комментарии? 2- Если вы о сложности операций упоминаете, то в худшем случае (для специально сконструированного ввода) квадратичное поведение может быть у словаря, а не линейное. В среднем (для случайного ввода) поведение линейное амортизированное. 3- Измерение производительности является тяжёлой задачей, поэтому не стоит большого внимания полученным цифрам придавать, если вы не провели работу по учёту многих, многих факторов. Переместите `counter = ..` из setup.

Comment: @jfs, спасибо за замечания. 1) Мешает невнимательность. 2) Не могли вы закинуть ссылку на пояснения по измерению производительности (в конце концов отдельные милисекунды не важны, а разница у 3 методов довольно большая)? Я не совсем представляю, что нужно такого сделать (и зачем?), чтобы нельзя было понять какой метод быстрее на определенных данных и насколько.

Comment: вопрос о производительности не стоял. Вы зачем-то начали какие-то  числа приводить (плюс у вас ошибка, которую я уже упомянул—один код заново создаёт словарь, другой с одним и тем же объектом работает—хотя результаты могут и не измениться в зависимости от ввода). Упоминание терминов из какой-то версии CPython  реализации создаёт неоправданное впечатление о широте применения результатов. Факторов, которые следует учесть море—единственная benchmark, которая важна это ваша программа на вашем же железе. Посмотрите какие слова о результатах приведены http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/

Comment: Не возражаете, если я немного структуры добавлю в этот вопрос?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, нет, конечно, не возражаю

Answer (score 14):

Есть же уже готовый Counter в модуле collections.

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter([10, 10, 23, 10, 123, 66, 78, 123])
print(c)
```

получаем вот что:
Counter({10: 3, 123: 2, 66: 1, 78: 1, 23: 1})

Comment: стоит отсеять уникальные элементы: `{e: count for e, count in c.items() if count > 1}`

Answer (score 10):

захотелось сравнить производительность для массива состоящего из 1.000.000 элементов:

Setup:

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

# random list (length: 1.000.000)
l = np.random.randint(1,100, 10**6).tolist()

# pandas DF
df = pd.DataFrame({'val':l})

# dict solution
def dct(A):
    counter = {}

    for elem in A:
        counter[elem] = counter.get(elem, 0) + 1

    return {key: counter[key] for key in filter(lambda elem: counter[elem] > 1, counter)}
```

Timing:

```
In [79]: %timeit Counter(l)
10 loops, best of 3: 48 ms per loop
```

сам по себе Counter - достаточно быстрый, но нам еще надо будет отфильтровать результат ...

```
In [80]: %timeit dct(l)
10 loops, best of 3: 178 ms per loop

In [81]: %timeit df.val.value_counts().reset_index().query('val > 1').rename(columns={'index':'val', 'val':'count'})
100 loops, best of 3: 14.4 ms per loop
```

Pandas demonstration:

```
In [71]: df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [10, 10, 23, 10, 123, 66, 78, 123]})

In [72]: %paste
(df.val
   .value_counts()
   .reset_index()
   .query('val > 1')
   .rename(columns={'index':'val', 'val':'count'})
)
## -- End pasted text --
Out[72]:
   val  count
0   10      3
1  123      2
```

Comment: Хм, Counter - потомок `dict`, и подсчет он ведет точно таким методом: `mapping[elem] = mapping.get(elem, 0) + 1`, и метод `get` не переопределен. Единственный момент, что есть типа реализация этой строки на С и если она импортируется, то используется именно она. Что они там могли написать?

Comment: Ага, так вот же настоящий счетчик для Counter - https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#l2204 - там какой-то адок - я обновлю свой ответ с поясненем, почему Counter быстрее.

Comment: @m9_psy, спасибо за ссылку - немного запутанно, но интересно

Answer (score 10):

Для случая, когда входной список отсортирован, можно использовать [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) вместо `{el: count for el, count in collections.Counter(L).items() if count > 1}`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from itertools import groupby

L = [10, 10, 23, 10, 123, 66, 78, 123]
duplicates = {}
for el, group in groupby(sorted(L)):
    count = len(list(group))
    if count > 1:
        duplicates[el] = count # element -> number of occurrences

print(duplicates) # -> {10: 3, 123: 2}
```

Если список неотсортирован, то сортировка это `O(n * log n)` операция. На практике следует измерять производительность разных вариантов, *если производительность этого кода имеет значение в вашем случае* (так как для небольшого `n`, `O(n * log n)` операция может быть быстрее `O(n)` операции, такой как с использованием `Counter()`).

Answer (score 6):

Если скорость выполнения не важна, то можно сделать так:

```
def test(lst):
    return {a: lst.count(a) for a in set(lst) if lst.count(a) > 1}

print(test([10, 10, 23, 10, 123, 66, 78, 123]))
```

Вывод:

> {10: 3, 123: 2}

Answer (score 0):

Один из способов решения этой задачи - использовать словарь. Можно создать словарь, в котором каждому элементу списка соответствует количество его повторений, и в цикле перебрать элементы списка, добавляя их в словарь.

Вот пример такой функции:

```
def count_repeats(lst):
    """
    Возвращает словарь, в котором каждому элементу списка lst соответствует
    количество его повторений.
    """
    repeats = {}
    for item in lst:
        if item in repeats:
            repeats[item] += 1
        else:
            repeats[item] = 1
    return repeats



# Пример использования функции
lst = [10, 10, 23, 10, 123, 66, 78, 123]
repeats = count_repeats(lst)
print(repeats)  # {10: 3, 123: 2}
```

Функция `count_repeats` принимает на вход список `lst`, перебирает его элементы и добавляет их в словарь `repeats`. Если элемент уже есть в словаре, то увеличивается значение соответствующей пары ключ-значение, если же элемента еще нет в словаре, то добавляется пара с ключом равным этому элементу и значением `1`.

Вы можете использовать эту функцию, чтобы найти повторяющиеся элементы в списке и количество их повторений.

---

Вы также можете использовать функцию Counter из модуля collections, чтобы посчитать количество повторений элементов списка. Эта функция возвращает словарь, в котором каждому элементу списка соответствует количество его повторений.

Вот пример кода, который использует функцию Counter:

```
from collections import Counter

def count_repeats(lst):
    """
    Возвращает словарь, в котором каждому элементу списка lst соответствует
    количество его повторений.
    """
    return Counter(lst)


# Пример использования функции
lst = [10, 10, 23, 10, 123, 66, 78, 123]
repeats = count_repeats(lst)
print(repeats)  # Counter({10: 3, 123: 2})
```

В этом коде сначала импортируется модуль `collections` и функция `Counter`, а затем определяется функция `count_repeats`, которая принимает список `lst` и возвращает результат вызова функции `Counter` на этом списке.

---

Вы также можете использовать функцию `most_common` из модуля `collections`, чтобы найти топ-N самых часто встречающихся элементов в списке. Эта функция принимает список и число N, и возвращает список кортежей, каждый из которых содержит элемент и количество его повторений.

Вот пример кода, который использует функцию `most_common`:

```
from collections import Counter

def find_top_repeats(lst, n):
    """
    Возвращает топ-N самых часто встречающихся элементов в списке lst.
    """
    return Counter(lst).most_common(n)


# Пример использования функции
lst = [10, 10, 23, 10, 123, 66, 78, 123]
top_repeats = find_top_repeats(lst, 2)
print(top_repeats)  # [(10, 3), (123, 2)]
```

В этом коде сначала импортируется модуль `collections` и функция `Counter`, а затем определяется функция `find_top_repeats`, которая принимает список `lst` и число `n`, и возвращает результат вызова функции `most_common`

---

Если вам нужно найти только уникальные элементы в списке, то можете использовать функцию set. Эта функция создает множество из элементов списка, удаляя повторяющиеся элементы. Множество не содержит повторяющихся элементов, поэтому вы можете использовать его, чтобы найти уникальные элементы в списке.

Вот пример кода, который использует функцию `set`:

```
def find_unique(lst):
    """
    Возвращает список уникальных элементов в списке lst.
    """
    return list(set(lst))


# Пример использования функции
lst = [10, 10, 23, 10, 123, 66, 78, 123]
unique = find_unique(lst)
print(unique)  # [66, 78, 10, 123, 23]
```

В этом коде определяется функция `find_unique`, которая принимает список `lst` и возвращает список уникальных элементов. Для этого список преобразуется в множество

---

Если вам нужно найти только уникальные элементы в списке и посчитать их количество, то можете соединить два предыдущих подхода: сначала использовать функцию `set` для нахождения уникальных элементов, а затем функцию `count_repeats` для подсчета их количества.

Вот пример кода, который реализует этот подход:

```
def count_unique(lst):
    """
    Возвращает словарь, в котором каждому уникальному элементу списка lst соответствует
    количество его повторений.
    """
    repeats = {}
    for item in set(lst):
        repeats[item] = lst.count(item)
    return repeats


# Пример использования функции
lst = [10, 10, 23, 10, 123, 66, 78, 123]
unique_counts = count_unique(lst)
print(unique_counts)  # {66: 1, 78: 1, 10: 3, 123: 2}
```

В этом коде определяется функция `count_unique`, которая принимает список `lst` и возвращает словарь, в котором каждому уникальному элементу списка

Answer (score -1):

```
#Добавление в словарь элементов списка и количества их вхождений:        
        
l = [10, 10, 23, 10, 123, 66, 78, 123]         
num = 0        
d = {}        
for i in l:        
   kol = l.count(l[num])        
   val = l[num]        
   num+=1        
   d[val] = kol       
print(d)        
        
#Результат:        
{10: 3, 23: 1, 123: 2, 66: 1, 78: 1}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: Очень плохо, квадратичная сложность алгоритма.