# Уникальные элементы списка

Tags: python

Дан список, заполненный произвольными целыми числами.

Получите новый список, элементами которого будут:

1. не повторяющиеся элементы исходного списка: например, `lst = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 2, 5, 2]`, нужно получить `lst2 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]`
2. элементы исходного списка, которые не имеют повторений:
   например, `lst = [1 , 2, 4, 5, 6, 2, 5, 2]`, нужно получить `lst2 = [1, 4, 6]`.

Comment: И в чем же ваша проблема?

Comment: Это задача для вас или для нас?

Answer (score 1):

https://ideone.com/jSMiI2

```
lst = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 2, 5, 2]

used = set()
unique = [x for x in lst if x not in used and (used.add(x) or True)]
print(unique)

from collections import Counter
counter = Counter(lst)

unique = list(counter)
print(unique)

single = [x for x,n in counter.items() if n==1]
print(single)
```

Источники:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/37163210/4928642
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/533128/178988
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter