# Вернуть элементы списка, встречающиеся более одного раза, не меняя очередность элементов

Tags: python, алгоритм

```
def checkio(a):
    #Your code here 
    #replace this for solution
    result=[]
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(a)):
            if a[i]==a[j] and i!=j:#если такие элементы есть
                result.append(a[i])#копируем в result  
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing
    #assert 
    assert list(checkio([1, 2, 3, 1, 3]))==[1,3,1,3]
    assert list(checkio([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])) == [], "2nd example"
    assert list(checkio([5, 5, 5, 5, 5]))== [5, 5, 5, 5, 5],checkio([5, 5, 5, 5, 5]) 
    assert list(checkio([10, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8])) == [10, 9, 10, 10, 9], checkio([10, 9, 10, 10, 9])
```

Но выходит такой assert:

```
assert list(checkio([5, 5, 5, 5, 5]))== [5, 5, 5, 5, 5],checkio([5, 5, 5, 5, 5]) 
AssertionError: [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как найти все дублирующиеся элементы в списке и количество их повторов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533108/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

def checkio(a):
    c = Counter(a)
    return [x for x in a if c[x] > 1]
```

Так без использования библиотек:

```
def checkio2(a):
    d = {}
    for x in a:
        d[x] = d.get(x, 0) + 1
    return [x for x in a if d[x] > 1]
```

Проверка:

```
In [324]: print(checkio([1, 2, 3, 1, 3]))
[1, 3, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Спасибо!Очень здорово)

Comment: Интересно было бы понять как запустить цикл в цикле(как у меня выше)и сравнивать элементы чтобы решить задачу,почему у меня в задаче это не получилось?

Comment: Не получилось, потому что каждую цифру 5 вы добавляете по четыре раза (в условии ``if a[i]==a[j] and i!=j``).

Comment: Давайте код сюда)