# Как узнать какие ключи имеет одинаковые значения?

Tags: python-3.x, структуры, структуры-данных

Есть словарь. Ключами выступают айдишники, значениями айпишки. Как узнать какие ключи имеет одинаковые значения? Словарь имеет вид

```
 '10214': '192.168.15.11',
 '10215': '192.168.15.12',
 '10216': '192.168.15.9',
 '10217': '192.168.15.7',
 '10218': '192.168.15.10',
 '10219': '192.168.15.102',
 '10220': '192.168.15.103',
 '10221': '192.168.15.104',
 '10222': '192.168.15.8',
 '10223': '192.168.15.36',
```

Хочу узнать какие айпишки дублируются. Подскажите как это можно сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы узнать какие ip встречаются больше одного раза:

```
from collections import Counter

dups = {ip for ip, count in Counter(id2ip.values()).items() if count > 1}
# -> {'192.168.15.102', '192.168.15.8'}
```

См. [Как найти все дублирующиеся элементы в списке и количество их повторов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/533535/23044)

Чтобы узнать какие id соответствуют повторяющимся ip, чтобы сгруппировать id по ip:

```
from collections import defaultdict

ip2ids = defaultdict(list)
for id, ip in id2ip.items():
    ip2ids[ip].append(id)

for ip, ids in ip2ids.items():
    if len(ids) > 1:
        print(f'{ip:15s}:', *ids)
```

Результат:

```
192.168.15.8   : 10216 10222
192.168.15.102 : 10218 10219
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_dict = {'10214': '192.168.15.11',
 '10216': '192.168.15.8',
 '10218': '192.168.15.102',
 '10219': '192.168.15.102',
 '10220': '192.168.15.103',
 '10221': '192.168.15.104',
 '10222': '192.168.15.8',
 '10223': '192.168.15.36',} 


for x,y in my_dict.items():
    if list(my_dict.values()).count(y) > 1:
        print(x,y)
```

Вывод:

10216 192.168.15.8
10218 192.168.15.102
10219 192.168.15.102
10222 192.168.15.8

Comment: ругается на .count, говорит, что такого нет.

Comment: извините, поправил под третий python

Comment: может, тогда, еще подскажешь как вывести все ключи по одинаковому значению?

Comment: kolas,  print(x,y) x - ключ, y - значение. значит просто print(x)

Comment: не, я понял, я просто думал можно как то сделать что бы был такой вид ['10216', '10222']: '192.168.15.8'

Comment: это квадратичный алгоритм, есть простое линейное решение.  См.  [в конце ответа о разнице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/596513/23044)