# В чем разница между двумя циклами for: при удалении элементов во время обхода списка

Tags: python, циклы, list, список, python-internals

Почему интерпретатор в первом случае убирает только 3 нуля `['1', '0', '0', '0']`, а во втором удаляет полностью, в чем разница? For - работает с каждым итерируемым объектом по очереди, почему он пропускает 3 нуля?

```
list1 = ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1']
for _ in list1:
    list1.remove('0') 
print(list1)

nuly = ['3', '2', '0', '0', '3', '5', '0', '0', '0', '8', '0'] 
for _ in nuly:
    nuly.remove('0')
print(nuly)
```

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Loop through a list in Python and modify it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44633798/4279)

Answer (score 13):

Оба цикла одинаковые. Только входные списки разные. Вы удаляете элементы из списка, одновременно обходя его.

При обходе списка, цикл `for` *не копирует* его, а создаёт итератор, который элементы из списка *по одному* возвращает. Поэтому когда вы удаляете элемент (`.remove('0')` ищет один `'0'` в списке и удаляет его), то список изменяется и эти изменения видны в итераторе.

В текущей реализации СPython, итератор списка хранит ссылку на сам список и текущий индекс в нём. Элементы возвращаются пока длина списка больше текущего индекса. Вот суть [`next(list_iterator)` вызова](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/63718f4154b0cb0e0bc672b6c38e00dfef70d111/Objects/listobject.c#L2765-L2787), возвращающего следующий элемент на каждой итерации:

```
listiter_next(listiterobject *it)
{
    ... 
    if (it->it_index < PyList_GET_SIZE(it->it_seq)) {
        item = PyList_GET_ITEM(seq, it->it_index);
        ++it->it_index;
        return item;
    }
    ...
}
```

Что на Питоне выглядит как:

```
if i < len(lst):
    item = lst[i]
    i += 1
    return item
```

Если по шагам выполнить код на [pythontutor.com](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=lst%20%3D%20%5B0,%20'0',%20'0',%20'0',%20'0',%20'0',%20'0',%20'0',%20'0',%209%5D%0Afor%20i,%20x%20in%20enumerate(lst%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20lst.remove('0'%29%20%0A%20%20%20%20size%20%3D%20len(lst%29%0Aprint(lst%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=18&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false):

```
#XXX BROKEN
lst = [0, '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 9]
for i, x in enumerate(lst):
    lst.remove('0') 
    size = len(lst)
print(lst) # -> [0, '0', '0', '0', 9]
```

Можно увидеть, что цикл продолжается до тех пор пока `i < size`. Поэтому цикл может завершиться до того как все `'0'` элементы удалены.

---

Если вы хотите удалить `'0'` из списка, то обычный способ:

```
lst[:] = [x for x in lst if x != '0']
```

Если не создавать временный список, то можно, обходя список, переносить значения, которые хочется оставить в начало списка, а затем [удалить все элементы в конце](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2794519/4279):

```
def remove_all(seq, value):
    pos = 0
    for item in seq:
        if item != value:
           seq[pos] = item
           pos += 1
    del seq[pos:]

remove_all(lst, '0')
```

Оба решения линейные—`O(n)`. Первое решение требует `O(n-k)` дополнительной памяти, где `k = lst.count('0')`.

Если известно, что в большом списке, только несколько значений нужно удалить (`k` маленькое и не зависит от `n`), то можно использовать удаление `del lst[i]`, обходя список в обратном порядке  (так как удаление не влияет на элементы в начале списка):

```
for i in reversed(range(len(lst))):
    if lst[i] == '0':
        del lst[i] # O(n) * k == O(n * k)
```

В общем случае это квадратичный алгоритм `O(n**2)`.

## Чем плохи квадратичные алгоритмы

Квадратичные решения могут быть заметно медленнее для больших `n`, чем линейные.

К примеру, линейный алгоритм для списка с миллионом элементов требует не больше чем `C1 * 1000_000` шагов (инструкций), в то время как квадратичный алгоритм `C2 * 1000_000_000_000`, где C1, C2 константы, не зависящие от размера входного списка. C1, C2 примерно (по порядку величины) равны в этом случае, поэтому линейный алгоритм гораздо более предпочтителен, если `k ~ n`.

Если миллион инструкций выполняются примерно за миллисекунду (даже моргнуть не успеете), то квадратичный алгоритм займёт целый день, если у кого-то терпения хватит ждать или батарейка не сядет пока закончится выполнение.

Миллион элементов не является каким-то большим вводом в современных условиях (телефоны гигабайты памяти имеют).

Как правило можно игнорировать константы (`C1`, `C2` в примере) вне горячих точек (hot spots), к примеру, если константа на порядок изменится (в 10 раз), то миллион инструкций линейного алгоритма займёт в 10 раз дольше: ~10 миллисекунд (всё равно быстрее чем моргнуть успеете) и гораздо меньше многих часов для квадратичного алгоритма с ~10<sup>12</sup> операций.

Подытоживая: записывая алгоритм, стоит ориентироваться на простоту, читаемость и может ли он в принципе выполнить поставленную задачу. Микро-оптимизациями, которые уродуют код, улучшая только константу (`C1`, `C2` в примере), лучше не заниматься, если profiler не говорит обратного. Если заранее не известно, что ввод ограничен по размеру, то стоит обратить внимание на порядок роста (big O) используемого алгоритма. В частности, если это заметно не затрудняет реализацию, то линейные алгоритмы (`O(n)`) гораздо более предпочтительны по сравнению с квадратичными (`O(n*n)`). Примеры из реального мира: https://accidentallyquadratic.tumblr.com/

Comment: Спасибо за подробное объяснение!

Answer (score 7):

Различие состоит в количестве элементов в контейнерах и количестве нулей в каждом из них.

Когда вы удаляете 0, то размер контейнера уменьшается. Например, для первого случая это можно представить следующим образом.

Пусть идентификатор `i` является индексом элементов последовательности, а идентификатор `n`  - общим количеством элементов в последовательности. После каждой итерации цикла индекс увеличивается на единицу, чтобы обратиться к следующему элементу.

Итак, для первого цикла начальные значения `i = 0, n = 10`. Теперь пройдемся по итерациям цикла

```
i = 0; remove( 0 ); n = 9
i = 1; remove( 0 ); n = 8
i = 2; remove( 0 ); n = 7
i = 3; remove( 0 ); n = 6
i = 4; remove( 0 ); n = 5
i = 5; n <= i итерация не выполняется.
```

В результате имеем, что было выполнено 5 удалений.

Это схематическое объяснение работы цикла. Реализация цикла может быть иной, но тем не менее данная модель демонстрирует, что используемый подход к удалению элементов из последовательности некорректен и ведет к непредсказуемому результату.