# Python 3.6 проблемы с сортировкой списка кортежей

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть отсортированный по последнему элементу в кортеже список:

```
current_list_sorted = [('144407', 1824832395, 19800, 175100), ('144407', 1824753815, 20499, 175100),
                       ('144407', 1824213258, 20999, 175100), ('144407', 1824176122, 21000, 175100),
                       ('144407', 1824169832, 22000, 175100), ('144407', 1824548868, 29500, 175100),
                       ('144406', 1824861645, 37999, 175100), ('144406', 1824644172, 37999, 175100),
                       ('144406', 1824610394, 38000, 175100), ('144406', 1824547218, 40450, 175100),
                       ('144406', 1824245759, 40600, 175100), ('144404', 1824843062, 57412, 175100),
                       ('144404', 1824537850, 57413, 175100), ('144407', 1824824742, 71999, 175100),
                       ('144403', 1824817390, 17500, 140080), ('144403', 1824564084, 17800, 140080),
                       ('144405', 1824843519, 18000, 140080), ('144403', 1824455877, 18000, 140080),
                       ('144403', 1824303625, 19990, 140080), ('144405', 1824591441, 19999, 140080),
                       ('144405', 1824544224, 20000, 140080), ('144405', 1824374436, 21982, 140080),
                       ('144405', 1824177630, 22000, 140080), ('144399', 1824715215, 23999, 140080),
                       ('144403', 1823958753, 24000, 140080), ('144401', 1824818068, 24499, 140080),
                       ('144405', 1824821563, 25000, 140080), ('144405', 1824548660, 27500, 140080),
                       ('144403', 1824709607, 27961, 140080), ('144399', 1824419957, 27998, 140080),
                       ('144399', 1824159251, 27999, 140080), ('144401', 1824136448, 30000, 140080),
                       ('144401', 1824201748, 30000, 140080), ('144401', 1823381545, 33749, 140080),
                       ('144405', 1824822373, 35000, 140080), ('144401', 1824710724, 40000, 140080),
                       ('144401', 1824547856, 42500, 140080), ('144401', 1824547821, 42500, 140080),
                       ('144405', 1824878835, 43000, 140080), ('144405', 1824722952, 47000, 140080),
                       ('144403', 1824692854, 49999, 140080), ('144403', 1824556640, 50000, 140080),
                       ('144405', 1824178089, 59999, 140080), ('144403', 1824340083, 60000, 140080),
                       ('144405', 1824543223, 60251, 140080), ('144401', 1824532563, 62479, 140080),
                       ('144405', 1824849452, 79999, 140080), ('144400', 1824680478, 18499, 84048),
                       ('144400', 1824547528, 18500, 84048), ('144400', 1824547533, 18500, 84048),
                       ('144400', 1824065492, 19500, 84048), ('144400', 1824202113, 20000, 84048),
                       ('144400', 1824547981, 22500, 84048), ('144400', 1823389155, 25000, 84048),
                       ('144400', 1823440710, 27999, 84048), ('144407', 1824877635, 2000, 2407),
                       ('144406', 1824616852, 250, 1162), ('144406', 1824616721, 250, 1162),
                       ('144405', 1824402073, 500, 930), ('144401', 1824659249, 749, 930),
                       ('144401', 1823572166, 750, 930), ('144405', 1824503373, 799, 930),
                       ('144400', 1824774740, 399, 558), ('144400', 1824731387, 400, 558),
                       ('144400', 1824593540, 497, 558), ('144400', 1824587010, 498, 558),
                       ('144400', 1824499922, 499, 558), ('144400', 1824402341, 550, 558)]
```

Мне нужно сделать так чтобы при переборе каждого элемента списка, он удалялся из списка и добавлялся в новый, проверялось по всему списку нет ли еще кортежей с таким же первый элементом в нем, и если находились то удалялись из старого списка и добавлялись в новый, для этого написал вот такое

```
while len(current_list_sorted) > 0:
    current = current_list_sorted.pop(0)
    temp_list = []
    temp_list.append((current[1:])) 
    for l in current_list_sorted:
        if l[0] == current[0]:
            temp_list.append(l[1:])
            current_list_sorted.remove(l)
            print(current[0])
            for lo in temp_list:
                print (lo)
```

Но на выходе в принте видно что не все кортежи отбираются через условие `if l[0] == current[0]` при том что они подходят, то есть в консоли печатается список кортежей например с первым элементом 144407, за ним сразу или через несколько других списков, еще один с таким же первым элементом, кортежи не повторяются.

Comment: Нельзя изменять коллекцию по которой идёт итерация.

Comment: странно вроде раньше делал так, похоже и тогда выходные данные былм не правильными, спс переделал подругому

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev: [можно, но только осторожно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/596463/23044)

Comment: @JobumJoben: для примера ввода, достаточно всего несколько значений, чтобы ввод и вывод продемонстрировать. Похоже вы хотите: `new_list = [tup for _, same_first_item_group in itertools.groupby(sorted(current_list_sorted, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0]) for tup in same_first_item_group]`?

Comment: допустим ввод: `[(2,'a'), (1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'b')]`, то какой вывод вы ожидаете? К примеру, `[(2,'a'), (2, 'b'), (1, 'a'), (1, 'b')]`? или `[(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2,'a'), (2, 'b')]`?

Comment: Какой вывод вы хотите?

Comment: спс за ответы, как я уже писал я сделал подругому, без модификации колекции, добавил новый список, по которому проверяю нет ли в нем текущего в итерации кортеж, если нет добавляю его список и все элементы у которых такой же первый элемент

Comment: на выходе получается такое (первый элемент в кортежах я оставил для наглядности групировки, у себя я его обрезаю):  `('144407', 1824832395, 19800, 175100), ('144407', 1824753815, 20499, 175100), и дальше все кортежи с первым элементом  144407                 ('144406', 1824861645, 37999, 175100), ('144406', 1824644172, 37999, 175100), и дальше все кортежи с первым 144406 и так далее все кортежи групируются по первому элементу`

Comment: 'если нет добавляю его список' добавляю В список, только заметил