# Удаление элементов с заданными индексами из списка

Tags: python, list

Привет всем! Есть 2 списка

```
list=[a,b,c,d,e,f]
```

и

```
numbers=[1,2,3]
```

Необходимо из списка list удалить элементы, использовав номера из numbers. То есть `numbers[0]=1` удаляет 'a'.На выходе получаем `list2[d,e,f]`.

Comment: Что вы попытались сделать и почему у вас не получилось?

Comment: я пытался из списка list удалить элементы ,которые идут идут под номера в numbers.Можно считать,что в numbers лежат индексы ,под которыми надо удалить элементы из list

Comment: отсортируйте numbers по убыванию и потом обычным циклом пройдитесь по индексам в numbers и удаляйте из list

Comment: @AndrewKonstantinov и таки почему ваша попытка оказалась неуспешной?

Comment: в этом и вопрос -как циклом пройтись по индексам и удалить из list

Comment: [Как циклом пройтись](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_Python_3.1#.D0.9E.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.80_for) — раз, [как удалить из list](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_Python_3.1#.D0.9F.D0.BE.D0.B4.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B1.D0.BD.D0.B5.D0.B5_.D0.BE_.D1.81.D0.BF.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B0.D1.85) — два. Вопрос решён?)

Comment: for i in range(len(list)): if numbers[i]==list.index(list[i]) list.remove(list[i]) так?

Comment: @andreymal, ну и где подробный ответ? :-)

Comment: @Grundy: стал не нужен))

Comment: @andreymal, а зря :-) два ответа лучше чем один, тем более если подробный :)

Comment: связанный вопрос: [В чем разница между двумя циклами for: при удалении элементов во время обхода списка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/596463/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При удалении элементов из списка важно учитывать, что после удаления индексы элементов, стоящих после удалённого, смещаются. Например, был список:

```
[a,b,c,d,e,f]
```

У `e` индекс `4` (счёт начинается с нуля). А теперь удалим `b`:

```
[a,c,d,e,f]
```

У `e` индекс стал `3`. Поэтому нельзя просто так брать список индексов и удалять по ним: индексы в этом списке станут указывать не туда, куда задумывалось.

Так как индексы сдвигаются только у элементов, стоящих *после* удаляемого, самый простой вариант решения проблемы — отсортировать список индексов по убыванию:

```
sorted(numbers, reverse=True)
```

Функция `sorted` возвращает отсортированный список, не меняя оригинальный.

Его можно сразу же использовать в цикле:

```
for n in sorted(numbers, reverse=True):
```

где `n` будет значениями из отсортированного списка `numbers`.

Для удаления элементов из списка можно использовать `del список[индекс]` или `список.pop(индекс)`. Второй отличается от первого тем, что возвращает удалённый элемент, и если он вам не нужен, то больше разницы между этими способами нет.

В вашем списке `numbers` счёт начинается с единицы, в то время как счёт индексов питоновых списков (а также кортежей, строк и т.п.) начинается с нуля, поэтому перед удалением от вашего индекса придётся отнять единицу.

Готовый код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
for n in sorted(numbers, reverse=True):
    del list[n - 1]
```

P.S. Не называйте переменные зарезервированными именами, `list` таковым является.

P.P.S. Возможно, выражение-генератор из соседних ответов — более хорошее решение, к тому же оно позволяет сохранить оригинальный список без удалённых элементов, если нужно

P.P.P.S. Не забывайте про обработку ошибок и проверку корректности индексов, если список `numbers` получен откуда попало и к его содержимому нет доверия

Answer (score 2):

Можно создать новый список, буквально указав, что в него должны входить элементы индекс которых не находится в массиве `numbers`

```
[x for ind,x in enumerate(l) if ind+1 not in numbers]
```

`(ind+1)` - так как индексы начинаются с `0`

[**Пример**](https://repl.it/IteZ)

<sub>На основе ответа [Pavel Anossov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14864937/2881286) на аналогичный вопрос.</sub>

Функция [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) возвращает итератор, метод [**next**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__) которого вернет кортеж из количества элементов со старта (второго параметра) и текущего элемента.

Таким образом можно убрать `+1` указав второй параметр

```
[x for ind,x in enumerate(l,1) if ind not in numbers]
```

[**Пример**](https://repl.it/IteZ/1)

Comment: спасибо за оперативный ответ

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, читайте доки и **никогда** не называйте переменные зарезервированными именами - `list`

Вот это: *`numbers[0]=1` удаляет 'a'* - Ваша вторая ошибка, если Вы решили учить програмирование, надо четко понимать, что элементы начинаются с нуль, как этажи в Турции. Ваше условие будет вводить в заблуждение.

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6
| a | b | c | d | e | f |
```

Можно сделать срез, для наглядности, который не вызовет ошибку не смотря на то, что элемента с индексом `6` нет

```
print(a.index(a[-1]))  # напечатаем индекс последнего эл-та списка, индекс 5
print(a[:6])
```

А вот если руководствоваться Вашим условием и выполнить `print(a[6])` получим ошибку:

> IndexError: list index out of range

Дальше, список - изменяемый объект, операции над списком будут изменять первоначальные данные, поэтому в зависимости от условия, надо либо создать новый список из имеющегося, либо изменить существующий, тут надо внимательно, можно потерять данные, изменить существующий список можно так:

```
my_list = [a, b, c, d, e, f] 
numbers = [0, 1, 2]  # изменил Ваше условие на более корректное
for i in sorted(numbers, reverse=True):
    print(my_list.pop(i))  # напечатает элемент, который удалил, для наглядности
```

Если нам ценны наши данные, то мы создаем новый список по условию:

```
my_list = [a, b, c, d, e, f] 
numbers = [0, 1, 2]
new_list = []
for i in my_list:
    if my_list.index(i) in numbers:
        print('position not append')
    else:
        new_list.append(i)
        print('position append in new list')
```

Или записать выражением-генератором, которое сократит потребление ОЗУ:

```
new_list = [i for i in my_list if my_list.index(i) not in numbers]
```

И вот [тут](https://www.codecademy.com/) Можно поупражняться

Answer (score 0):

Репутации не хватает оставить коммент по месту.
Думаю, что решение предложенное выше 'andreymal', а именно:
for n in sorted(numbers, reverse=True):
    del list[n - 1]
-самое простое и конструктивное. Очень мне помогло при сортировке списка словарей с объединением значений по ключу и удалением дубликатов элементов с одинаковым ключом.
однако с [n-1] не согласен!
Рабочий код будет таким в данном случае:

```
del_index = [1, 3, 5]  
val_list = ['0 dfg', '1 tr', '2 er++', '3 +', '4__', '5 zxcvb']
for n in sorted(del_index, reverse=True):
    del val_list[n]
    print(val_list)
```

т.е. с [n] вместо [n-1] всё работает корректно.