# Как создать сортировщик по буквам: отсортировать список слов по первым буквам с заданным порядком букв

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x

Как создать сортировщик по буквам. От любой буквы до любой буквы? (на python 3)
вот собственно написал код:

```
list=["e","r","t","y","w"]
h=0
list2=["write","english","teacher","read","yellow"]
enter=[]
for u in range(1000):           #while len(enter)<=4:
    for qw in list2:
        try:
            if qw[0]==list[h]:
                enter.append(qw)
                h=h+1
        except IndexError:
            pass
print(enter)
```

но минус этого кода в том что при случии если в списке list 2 встретиться допустим два слова на букву r то напечатает слово на букву r которая стоит ближе к началу списка это происходит из-за того что я делаю переменную h которая показывает на какая будет следующая буква.

Используется Python 3.6.1

Comment: Первое, не используйте имена переменных как базовые классы. Второе, *map()* и *filter()* прекрасно работают со строкой как с iterable object. Третье, если я правильно понял задачу, вам нужна рекурсия по словарю-ключу (то, что у вас выполняет роль list1).

Comment: Вы задаете свое правило сортировки в списке `list`?

Comment: да правила задаются в list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list1=["e","r","t","y","w"]
list2=["write","english","teacher","read","yellow"]

enter = [y for x in list1 for y in list2 if x == y[0]]

print(enter)
```

Comment: Стоит заметить, что это квадратичный алгоритм O(n**2), если длины list1, list2 не ограничены. Для данной задачи легко получить O(n log n) алгоритм. [Квадратичный алгоритм может растянуть секундную операцию на целый день](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/596513/23044)

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы отсортировать список слов по первым буквам, используя порядок букв, определяемый другим списком (алфавит), предполагая что алфавит маленький и его длина не зависит от ввода, есть простое O(n * log n) решение:

```
def sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet):
    return sorted(words, key=lambda word: alphabet.index(word[0]))
```

Если результаты вызова `alphabet.index()` закэшировать, то получится решение из [@MaxU ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/711873/23044).

Для бо́льшего ввода, есть линейный алгоритм O(n + m):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet):
    words_by_char = defaultdict(list)  # char -> words
    for word in words:
        words_by_char[word[0]].append(word)
    return [word for char in alphabet for word in words_by_char.get(char) or []]
```

где `n` — это количество слов, `m` — количество букв в алфавите. Пример:

```
>>> alphabet = "wtrye"
>>> words = ["write", "english", "teacher", "read", "yellow", "red"]
>>> sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet)
['write', 'teacher', 'read', 'red', 'yellow', 'english']
```

### Сравнение производительности

*Кратко*: сюрпризов нет. На небольшом вводе особой разницы во времени исполнения нет (поэтому самое простое решение предпочтительно). На большом вводе асимптотика решений даёт себя знать (если важна производительность, используйте подходящий алгоритм).

#### n, m ~ 1

Для маленького ввода, все реализации (`sorted_by_first_char()` выше +  [другие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/711873/23044) [решения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/711794/23044) [задачи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/711713/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python-3-6-1/711873?noredirect=1#comment1065559_711873)) занимают примерно одинаковое время 3-5 микросекунд на моей машине:

```
$ python -m perf timeit -s $'def sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet):\n\torder = {c:i for i,c in enumerate(alphabet)}\n\treturn sorted(words, key=lambda w: order[w[0]])\nalphabet = "wtrye"\nwords = ["write", "english", "teacher", "read", "yellow", "red"]' 'sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet)' 
.....................
Mean +- std dev: 4.61 us +- 0.16 us

$ python -m perf timeit -s $'from collections import defaultdict\ndef sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet):\n\twords_by_first_char = defaultdict(list)\n\tfor word in words:\n\t\twords_by_first_char[word[0]].append(word)\n\treturn [word for char in alphabet for word in words_by_first_char[char]]\nalphabet = "wtrye"\nwords = ["write", "english", "teacher", "read", "yellow", "red"]' 'sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet)'
.....................
Mean +- std dev: 4.80 us +- 0.21 us

$ python -m perf timeit -s $'def sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet):\n\treturn sorted(words, key=lambda word: alphabet.index(word[0]))\nalphabet = "wtrye"\nwords = ["write", "english", "teacher", "read", "yellow", "red"]' 'sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet)'
.....................
Mean +- std dev: 4.40 us +- 0.15 us

$ python -m perf timeit -s $'def sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet):\n\treturn [w for c in alphabet for w in words if c == w[0]]\nalphabet = "wtrye"\nwords = ["write", "english", "teacher", "read", "yellow", "red"]' 'sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet)'                                 
.....................
Mean +- std dev: 3.23 us +- 0.08 us
```

#### m ~ 10, n ~ 10_000*m

```
$ python -m perf timeit -s $'import string\ndef sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet):\n\torder = {c:i for i,c in enumerate(alphabet)}\n\treturn sorted(words, key=lambda w: order[w[0]])\nalphabet = string.ascii_lowercase\nwords = list(alphabet)*10000' 'sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet)'  
.....................
Mean +- std dev: 105 ms +- 2 ms

$ python -m perf timeit -s $'import string\nfrom collections import defaultdict\ndef sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet):\n\twords_by_first_char = defaultdict(list)\n\tfor word in words:\n\t\twords_by_first_char[word[0]].append(word)\n\treturn [word for char in alphabet for word in words_by_first_char[char]]\nalphabet = string.ascii_lowercase\nwords = list(alphabet)*10000' 'sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet)'
.....................
Mean +- std dev: 48.8 ms +- 1.3 ms

$ python -m perf timeit -s $'import string\ndef sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet):\n\treturn sorted(words, key=lambda word: alphabet.index(word[0]))\nalphabet = string.ascii_lowercase\nwords = list(alphabet)*10000' 'sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet)'
.....................
Mean +- std dev: 150 ms +- 3 ms

$ python -m perf timeit -s $'import string\ndef sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet):\n\treturn [w for c in alphabet for w in words if c == w[0]]\nalphabet = string.ascii_lowercase\nwords = list(alphabet)*10000' 'sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet)'
.....................
Mean +- std dev: 508 ms +- 17 ms
```

Квадратичное решение начинает отставать.

#### n, m ~ 1000_000

Для большого алфавита (все Unicode символы) не квадратичные решения, использующие словари гораздо быстрее. Они выполняются порядка секунды:

```
$ python -m perf timeit -s $'import sys\ndef sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet):\n\torder = {c:i for i,c in enumerate(alphabet)}\n\treturn sorted(words, key=lambda w: order[w[0]])\n\nwords = alphabet = "".join(map(chr, range(sys.maxunicode+1)))' 'sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet)'
.....................
Mean +- std dev: 934 ms +- 30 ms

$ python -m perf timeit -s $'import sys\nfrom collections import defaultdict\ndef sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet):\n\twords_by_first_char = defaultdict(list)\n\tfor word in words:\n\t\twords_by_first_char[word[0]].append(word)\n\treturn [word for char in alphabet for word in words_by_first_char[char]]\n\nwords = alphabet = "".join(map(chr, range(sys.maxunicode+1)))' 'sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet)'.....................
Mean +- std dev: 1.83 sec +- 0.05 sec
```

Квадратичные алгоритмы (решение из [@Dmitry Erohin ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/711794/23044) и [моего комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/711713/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python-3-6-1/711873?noredirect=1#comment1065559_711873)) требуют порядка 10<sup>12</sup> операций в этом случае, то есть если выполнять по миллиарду операций в секунду, то порядка часа займёт выполнение, что заметно хуже не квадратичных решений.

Стоит обратить внимание, что `O(n log n + m)` решение из [@MaxU ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/711873/23044) выполняется быстрее `O(n + m)` решения из этого ответа на уже отсортированном вводе (особенность timsort алгоритма, используемого в sorted() в Питоне).

Это подтверждается измерениями на перемешанном вводе (разница меньше во времени):

```
$ python -m perf timeit -s $'import random, sys\nfrom collections import defaultdict\ndef sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet):\n\twords_by_first_char = defaultdict(list)\n\tfor word in words:\n\t\twords_by_first_char[word[0]].append(word)\n\treturn [word for char in alphabet for word in words_by_first_char[char]]\n\nalphabet = "".join(map(chr, range(sys.maxunicode+1)))\nwords = list(alphabet)\nrandom.shuffle(words)' 'sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet)'
.....................
Mean +- std dev: 2.93 sec +- 0.06 sec

$ python -m perf timeit -s $'import random, sys\ndef sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet):\n\torder = {c:i for i,c in enumerate(alphabet)}\n\treturn sorted(words, key=lambda w: order[w[0]])\n\nalphabet = "".join(map(chr, range(sys.maxunicode+1)))\nwords = list(alphabet)\nrandom.shuffle(words)' 'sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet)'
.....................
Mean +- std dev: 2.22 sec +- 0.07 sec
```

#### m ~ 1000_000, n ~ 10*m

При увеличении `n`, линейное решение выигрывает:

```
$ python -m perf timeit -s $'import random, sys\nfrom collections import defaultdict\ndef sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet):\n\twords_by_first_char = defaultdict(list)\n\tfor word in words:\n\t\twords_by_first_char[word[0]].append(word)\n\treturn [word for char in alphabet for word in words_by_first_char[char]]\n\nalphabet = "".join(map(chr, range(sys.maxunicode+1)))\nwords = list(alphabet)*10\nrandom.shuffle(words)' 'sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet)'
.....................
Mean +- std dev: 14.2 sec +- 0.4 sec

$ python -m perf timeit -s $'import random, sys\ndef sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet):\n\torder = {c:i for i,c in enumerate(alphabet)}\n\treturn sorted(words, key=lambda w: order[w[0]])\n\nalphabet = "".join(map(chr, range(sys.maxunicode+1)))\nwords = list(alphabet)*10\nrandom.shuffle(words)' 'sorted_by_first_char(words, alphabet)'
.....................
Mean +- std dev: 18.1 sec +- 0.4 sec
```

Comment: У меня вопрос я не всегда связываюсь с модулем collections, можете рассказать что делает функция defaultdict

Comment: @Gleb defaultdict здесь используется, чтобы вместо `if key not in d:  d[key] = []` а затем `d[key].append(value)` кода для обычного словаря, писать просто: `d[key].append(value)` — в случае с `d = defaultdict(list)` списки для отсутствующих ключей автоматически создаётся.

Answer (score 1):

Пример нестандартной ("custom") сортировки:

```
In [115]: lst1 = ["w","t","r","y","e"]

In [116]: lst2 = ["write","english","teacher","read","yellow", "red"]

In [117]: order = {x:i for i,x in enumerate(lst1)}

In [118]: sorted(lst2, key=lambda x: order[x[0]])
Out[118]: ['write', 'teacher', 'read', 'red', 'yellow', 'english']
```

вспомогательный словарь:

```
In [119]: order
Out[119]: {'e': 4, 'r': 2, 't': 1, 'w': 0, 'y': 3}
```

Comment: не ясно, зачем минус ответу поставили. Код рабочий (`O(n log n)`). Похожий вариант: учитывая, что первый список это алфавит, то  есть можно считать len(lst1) ~ O(1), тогда `sorted(words, key=lambda word: alphabet.index(word[0]))`