# Python. Сортировка списка по шаблону

Tags: python-3.5

Здравствуйте, допустим у меня есть такой список

```
ls = ['key_0', 'key_1', 'key_2']
```

Мне нужно отсортировать следующий список

```
result = [['key_1', 'val_1'], ['key_2', 'val_2'], ['key_0', 'val_0']]
```

так чтобы ключ-значение были в таком же порядке, как у первого списка.
Не подскажете?

Comment: связанный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/711713/23044

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
key2rank = {key: rank for rank, key in enumerate(ls)} 
result.sort(key=lambda key_value: key2rank[key_value[0]])
```