# Количество точек с целыми координатами в пересечении окружностей

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x, геометрия

Есть две окружности, заданные 2я координатами и радиусом - `(x1, y1, r1)`, `(x2, y2, r2)`.

Необходимо найти количество точек с целыми координатами, которые находятся одновременно в двух окружностях. Все значения по модулю не превосходят 10<sup>6</sup>.

UPD:
Вот моя попытка:

```
x1, y1, r1 = map(int, input().split(' '))
x2, y2, r2 = map(int, input().split(' '))

size_x_min = min([x1-r1, x2-r2])
size_x_max = max([x1+r1, x2+r2])
size_y_min = min([y1-r1, y2-r2])
size_y_max = max([y1+r1, y2+r2])

r1 = r1**2
r2 = r2**2

count = 0

for y in range(size_y_min, size_y_max):
    for x in range(size_x_min, size_x_max):
        if (x1 - x)**2 + (y1 - y)**2 <= r1 and (x2 - x)**2 + (y2 - y)**2 <= r2:
            count += 1
print(count)
```

Но код выполняется слишком медленно.

Пример:
окр 1 - `(0, 0, 5)`
окр 2 - `(2, 2, 3)`
Точек (ответ) - `26`

Comment: related: [Finding all points common to two circles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2730969/4279)

Comment: не относится напрямую к вопросу: интересное видео о связи количества точек на координатной решётке, находящихся внутри круга, простых чисел, комплексных чисел и π https://youtu.be/NaL_Cb42WyY

Comment: А почему вы принесли сюда олимпиадную задачу? Олимпиадные задачи нужно решать самому. Я надеюсь, кто-нибудь сообщит организаторам олимпиады об этом вопросе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Но код выполняется слишком медленно

Ваш алгоритм квадратичный по радиусу. Использование меньшего из двух радиусов этого не изменит. В худшем случае один круг в другом лежит, поэтому количество точек в
пересечении равно количеству точек в меньшем круге. Количество точек,
лежащих на координатной решётке, внутри круга пропорционально площади
круга, то есть ~r<sup>2</sup>. Поэтому любой метод, в котором точки по
одной считаются, будет квадратичным, то есть ведёт к ~10<sup>12</sup>
операций в этом случае (медленно).

Можно использовать линейный алгоритм, чтобы улучшить эффективность для больших радиусов. [В конце ответа по
ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/596513/23044) подробное
объяснение почему квадратичный алгоритм гораздо хуже линейного (для
больших радиусов).

Чтобы получить линейный алгоритм, можно обходить только одну координату (к примеру, вертикально по `y`), а количество точек (горизонтальных) в пересечении вычислять сразу, определяя пересечение интервалов, ограниченных заданными окружностями:

```
from math import ceil, floor

def count_lattice_points_intersection(a, b):
    count = 0
    for y in range(a.y - a.r, a.y + a.r + 1):  # scan from bottom to top
        if b.y - b.r <= y <= b.y + b.r:  # intersection is possible
            # find intersection boundaries for given y
            ax1, ax2 = x_coordinates_intesect(a, y)
            bx1, bx2 = x_coordinates_intesect(b, y)
            if min(ax2, bx2) >= max(ax1, bx1):  # intersect
                count += floor(min(ax2, bx2)) - ceil(max(ax1, bx1)) + 1
    return count

def x_coordinates_intesect(c, y):
    """Get x-coordinates of intersection of circle *c* and horizontal line *y*."""
    # solve quadratic equation
    # (x - c.x)**2 + (y - c.y)**2 == c.r**2
    assert c.r**2 >= (y - c.y)**2
    D = (c.r**2 - (y - c.y)**2)**.5
    return c.x - D, c.x + D
```

Границы интервалов находятся решив квадратное уравнение для окружности:

```
(x - c.x)**2 + (y - c.y)**2 == c.r**2
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/WQU2tV):

[image: lattice points of two circles intersection]

```
from collections import namedtuple

Circle = namedtuple('Circle', 'x, y, r')
print(count_lattice_points_intersection(Circle(0, 0, 5), Circle(2, 2, 3)))
# -> 26
```

`26` точек координатной решётки находятся внутри заданных кругов.

Answer (score 2):

Вы перебираете точки квадрата, содержащего обе окружности. Это правильное решение, но таких точек слишком много. В качестве начального квадрата достаточно взять квадрат, в который вписана меньшая окружность (точнее, надо говорить о кругах, а не окружностях).

Comment: это может поменять константу, но алгоритм всё равно останется квадратичным по величине радиуса (~10^12 операций). Существует [линейное решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/738994/23044)

Comment: @jfs Вы абсолютно правы, и Ваш ответ, разумеется, существенно эффективнее (код не смотрел, но описание алгоритма совершенно верное). Интересно, существует ли алгоритм быстрее О(r)?

Comment: Даже более простая задача о количестве точек координатной решётки внутри одного круга не имеет замкнутой формулы ([Проблема круга Гаусса](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0_%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0)) — ошибка (отличие от площади круга) точно не известна (оценка r**(1/2+eps)). [О(r)-решение](https://ideone.com/WQU2tV).