# Алгоритм поиска часто встречающейся записи в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список:

```
['a, b, c', 'b, c, a', 'c, a, b', 'a, b, c', 'a, b, c', 'b, a, c']
```

Надо найти часто повторяющуюся запись в списке и подсичитать количество повторений и самую меньше всего повторяющуюся запись и подсчитать количество повторений.

Помогите с алгоритмом, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
In [146]: from collections import Counter

In [147]: l =  ['a, b, c', 'b, c, a', 'c, a, b', 'a, b, c', 'a, b, c', 'b, a, c']

In [148]: c = Counter(l)

In [149]: c
Out[149]: Counter({'a, b, c': 3, 'b, a, c': 1, 'b, c, a': 1, 'c, a, b': 1})
```

чаще всего встречающийся элемент:

```
In [150]: c.most_common(1)[0]
Out[150]: ('a, b, c', 3)
```

реже всего встречающийся элемент:

```
In [151]: c.most_common()[-1]
Out[151]: ('b, a, c', 1)
```

можно легко реализовать нечто похожее самому воспользовавшись словарем:

```
In [175]: d = {x:l.count(x) for x in l}

In [176]: d
Out[176]: {'a, b, c': 3, 'b, a, c': 1, 'b, c, a': 1, 'c, a, b': 1}

In [177]: max(d, key=d.get)
Out[177]: 'a, b, c'

In [178]: d[max(d, key=d.get)]
Out[178]: 3

In [179]: min(d, key=d.get)
Out[179]: 'b, c, a'

In [180]: d[min(d, key=d.get)]
Out[180]: 1
```

[вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496518/python-using-a-dictionary-to-count-the-items-in-a-list) и [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-to-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item) более быстрые способы посчитать число вхождений:

```
In [193]: d = {}

In [194]: _ = [d.__setitem__(x,1+d.get(x,0)) for x in l]

In [195]: d
Out[195]: {'a, b, c': 3, 'b, a, c': 1, 'b, c, a': 1, 'c, a, b': 1}
```

---

```
In [196]: d = {}

In [197]: for x in l:
     ...:     d[x] = d.get(x, 0) + 1
     ...:

In [198]: d
Out[198]: {'a, b, c': 3, 'b, a, c': 1, 'b, c, a': 1, 'c, a, b': 1}
```

Comment: Отлично! То, что как раз и требуется! Большое спасибо!

Comment: Можно упомянуть временную сложность алгоритмов: вариант с `l.count(x)` имеет квадратичную сложность, `c.most_common()` — O(n log n). Есть линейное решение.  Примеры почему линейное решение может быть гораздо лучше квадратичного с ростом ввода [см. в конце ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/596513/23044)

Comment: Counter уже словарь: `min(c, key=c.get)`