# Чем отличается for i in A и for i in range(len(A))

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, сортировка

Вот я хочу перебросить элементы из одного списка в другой, чтобы в другом они располагались по возрастанию. Но почему, когда я пишу:

```
def Sort(A):
    lst = []
    for element in A:
        x = min(A)
        lst.append(x)
        A.remove(x)
    return lst
list2 = [9, 8 , 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
list3 = Sort(list2)
print(list3)
```

выводит [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], то есть половину элементов. А если вместо A написать range(len(A)):

```
def Sort(A):
    lst = []
    for element in range(len(A)):
        x = min(A)
        lst.append(x)
        A.remove(x)
    return lst
list2 = [9, 8 , 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
list3 = Sort(list2)
print(list3)
```

то все выводится верно. [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]. В чем отличие? Ведь и там, и там я перебираю элементы списка. Только в первом случае я этот перебор делаю по элементам, а во втором по индексам. Какая разница как именно это делать? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: В первом случае вы меняете список, по которому проходитесь, и тем самым ломаете цикл. Во втором случае вы индекс из цикла вообще не используете.

Comment: В обоих случах вместо цикла for можно написать просто `while A:`

Comment: @andreymal как не использую индекс в цикле? а что тогда такое range(len(A))? Ведь по сути range(len(A)) = 0, 1, 2, ..., len(A) -1, что соответствует индексации элементов в списке

Comment: Да, соответствует, только вот вы эту индексацию не используете абсолютно никак — переменная `element`, хранящая в себе этот самый индекс, нигде не используется.

Comment: "во втором по индексам" - это неверно.

Comment: @andreymal так а почему тогда во втором случае код работает, а в первом нет?

Comment: Потому что выражение range(len(A)) вычисляется один раз, перед циклом, и в данном случае, это просто range(10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом варианте, когда вы используете список, то он каждый раз считывается заново, таким образом когда он просчитывает пять элементов и список из которого вы берете тоже становится длиной из пяти элементов, то он на шестой итерации думает что перебрал весь список из-за того что он состоит в настоящий момент из пяти элементов.

Во втором варианте len(A) почему то не изменяется, и поэтому он переберет все элементы как и должен.

Если вы не изменяете список который перебираете - первый вариант лучше. В вашем случае нужен второй вариант.

Comment: но почему во втором случае код работает нормально, если, по идее, длина списка тоже изменяется?

Comment: а вот я хз, но это как то работает. я подумал минуты две над этим и я понятия не имею как это работает. может быть после того как все это идет в range(), оно уже не может измениться

Comment: есть челик у которого точно такой же вопрос был, почитайте, может поймете: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/596463/%d0%92-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-for-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bf?rq=1